# how do i open my JavaFX runnable JAR file without adding VM options?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

Hello I started yesterday learning Java-FX. After Hours of researching my errors I finally creacted a new windows user (because my username had a space in it and my username was bound to my microsoft account) and folowd this [youtube-tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbCmzOlkwAU&t=381s) step by step. Most of my problems seemed to be solved. i even stopped yousing the e(fx)clipse for aclipse-markedplace. But one problem still remains. i cant open runnable jar files by double-clicking. nothing happens. And when running in terminal i get this error-message:`java -jar test.jar Fehler: Zum Ausführen dieser Anwendung benötigte JavaFX-Runtime-Komponenten fehlen`  but i i run it using my VM options it works: `java -jar --module-path C:\JavaFX-SDK-17\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml  test.jar`. I used File / Export / Java / Runnable JAR file to create it.
What can i do? I have seen it work on other people's machine's.

I asked chat-GPT if it had something to do with the module-info that i didn't create? Doesnt helped me. And btw i get these waring after exporting the project:

```
JAR export finished with warnings. See details for additional information.
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
  duplicate entry: module-info.class
.....
```

Comment: If your aim is to distribute an executable jar file other users can simply run, that really isn't supported in JavaFX since it became modular. A better option is to create a native package that contains a JVM, and bundle the JavaFX modules with that package. The `jpackage` tool can help you do this. There is an extensive list of links in the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info) page, under the "Packaging" section, that addresses this.

Comment: Exporting it as a _Runnable JAR_ creates a fat JAR by merging all JARs (your code and the required dependencies) into a single JAR. But this does not work for [JPMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) where each module must be a JAR of its own containing a `module-info.class` in the root directory of the JAR.

Comment: If you are creating a fat JAR, then you should exclude any and all `module-info.class` files. And if you are trying to create an _executable_ fat JAR for a JavaFX application (with JavaFX included in the JAR), then your main class cannot be your `javafx.application.Application` subclass; create a separate launcher class and use that class as your main class.

Comment: This repository explains how it is done with Maven: https://github.com/davidweber411/javafx-JavaFxAppMavenNonModular